# Got an issue with using google script on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

1. Situation

Here's the solution that I'm trying to use about sending a message to my registered email via google script on my portfolio site. 
https://github.com/dwyl/learn-to-send-email-via-google-script-html-no-server

Currently I've built my portfolio with React.js.

2. Issue

The issue is that it doesn't print `thankyou_message` even after the mail has been successfully sent, which means I only see {"result": "success", ...} on the webpage.

3. What I've tried

I attached `form-submission-handler.js` in public folder, and the place where I added the tag(`<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="form-submission-handler.js"></script>`) is in the index.html in public folder, like below.

```js
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script data-cfasync="false" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/form-submission-handler.js"></script>
</body>
```

It seems like I've attached the `script tag` on wrong place, I'm not sure though.
If it is not the way or place to use this solution in JSX, could you please let me know?

Comment: did you add "<div style="display:none" class="thankyou_message">" for the `thankyou_message` ?

Comment: @novonimo yeah for sure I did. I followed the instruction of the link.